# Full games archive in FIDE Arena

Tags: online-chess, online-blitz

On the screenshot below it says that a paying member of the FIDE Arena has unlimited access to a full games archive. Unfortunately, for almost a year I have been unable to locate the place where my games are stored in the interface. I wrote to support but received no answer. Can anyone help me navigate the interface to find those games or confirm that they are lying about their service?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Log in to your account.
Stay on the Home tab(top left), on the right side there a section called Tournament/Challenges section. This has an adjustable date selection option. Select the start date and end date; or leave the default dates in place and hit Ok. 
There will be a need screen that loads that will list your game history based on the dates. Double click on each game and there you can download each game as .pgn files or just play over it again,

Hope this helps.

Comment: The complete path is: first the Home tab (on the left) and then the Details tab (on the right). But I have tried this before and they always show an alert saying that the service is not available at the moment please try again later and it's been like that for almost a year.